# Предзагрузка скрипта в chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Необходимо изменить значение свойства window.devicePixelRatio, которое используется в коде скрипта (условно common.js). При подключении этого скрипта не используется defer. Мой же скрипт, запускаемый расширением, запускается значительно позже этого скрипта.

Возможно ли загружать скрипт из расширения до загрузки страницы?

Comment: [оно?](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time)

Comment: Ты мой спаситель. Да, оно.
"run_at": "document_start"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Документация [здесь](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time), в `manifest.json` нужно добавить `run_at` со значением `document_start`

Пример

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "run_at": "document_start",
        "js": ["common.js"]
    }
],
```